# Self Attributes Live in Function Pointer?

Tags: python, python-3.4

Suppose I have a simple python3 class like so:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'
    def checkIsA(self, checkA):
        return self.a == checkA
```

And some further code such as:

```
def tester(func, item):
    return func(item)

testObject = Test()
print(tester(testObject.checkIsA, 'a'))  # prints True
```

How is the function pointer(?) checkIsA still aware of its class member variables (defined by self) when used independently by another function?

I want to use this functionality in a program I'm writing but I'm worried I'm not understanding these semantics correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testObject.checkIsA` is what's called a bound method - it remembers the instance it was taken from so that its `self` attribute gets automatically populated by that instance.

You can easily check a difference between a class function (unbound method) and an instance method (bound method), Python will quite happily tell you all the details:

```
testObject = Test()

print(Test.checkIsA)        # <function Test.checkIsA at 0x00000000041236A8>
print(testObject.checkIsA)  # <bound method Test.checkIsA of
                            # <__main__.Test object at 0x0000000004109390>>
```

You can simulate a call to `testObject.checkIsA()` directly through the unbound `Test.checkIsA` function by passing your instance, too, e.g.:

```
def tester(func, instance, item):
    return func(instance, item)

testObject = Test()
print(tester(Test.checkIsA, testObject, 'a'))  # prints True
```

Or, with `functools.partial`:

```
import functools

def tester(func, item):
    return func(item)

testObject = Test()
print(tester(functools.partial(Test.checkIsA, testObject), 'a'))  # prints True
```

And that's exactly what a bound instance method does for you in the back by supplementing the first `self` attribute with its stored `__self__` value. You can check that, too:

```
testObject = Test()
print(testObject.checkIsA.__self__ is testObject)  # True
```